# How to use New-AzDataLakeGen2Item to send multiple files under a directory

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

Based on [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azdatalakegen2item?view=azps-6.4.0) from Microsoft

**-Source**
- Specify the local source file path which will be upload to a Datalake Gen2 file.

```
TABLE 13
Type:   String
Position:   Named
Default value:  None
Accept pipeline input:  True
Accept wildcard characters: False  <-- no wildcard?
```

The doc also provided an example

```
PS C:\> $task = New-AzDataLakeGen2Item  -FileSystem "testfilesystem" -Path "dir1/dir2/file1" -Source "c:\sourcefile.txt" -Force -asjob
```

Then what if I'd like to send all files under a directory, so that

```
-Source "c:\temp\*" <-- wildcard not allowed
-Source "c:\temp\" <-- "Could not find file..."
```

instead of

```
-Source "c:\sourcefile.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to upload multiple files using `New-AzDataLakeGen2Item` Cmdlet.

You can however make use of [`azcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy) tool to upload multiple files. Based on the documentation, it supports copy files from local to ADLS Gen2 account (and vice-versa) among other things.

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy.